# Сравнение json обьектов в python

Tags: python, json

Есть 2 json объекта:

```
{'name':'pupkin', 'age':'40', 'sity': ['SPB'], 'cars':['Lada', 'Moskvich']}
{'name':'pupkin', 'age':'40', 'sity': ['SPB', 'Moskow'], 'cars':['Lada']}
```

Возможно ли провести сравнение этих двух объектов не прибегая к парсингу каждого ключа в первом и втором объекте?
В итоге я хочу провести мердж этих 2х обьектов в 1 со всеми изменениями. За эталонный берется любой из двух объектов (в данном случае например первый).   Должно получится так:

```
{'name':'pupkin', 'age':'40', 'sity': ['SPB'], 'cars':['Lada', 'Moskvich']}
```

Comment: Делай сразу мерж, какая разница если они одинаковые то схлопнутся. Не будешь 2 раза бегать

Comment: @AzizUmarov не совсем понял

Comment: "В итоге я хочу провести мердж этих 2х обьектов в 1 со всеми изменениями". Не в итоге, делайте всегда.

Comment: Тогда и сравнивать не надо будет

Comment: почему у вас в мердже sity только spb?

Comment: что вы хотите сделать? это изначально json-строки или объекты?
если хотите, чтоб в `a` было то, что в `b`, может это просто `a=b`?

Comment: @strawdog вот в этом то вся и загвоздка. Нужно удалить "Moskow" из второго массива. Если в лоб, то нужно сравнивать 1 к 2, а потом 2 к 1, вот я и интересуюсь есть ли способ не делать двойную работу?

Comment: А чем не подходит способ -- вообще не делать работу?
Есть эталонный объект, можно брать и пользоваться.

Comment: Просто возникает чувство, что вопрос задан в рамках какой-то сложной задачи.
И, возможно, эта задача решается лучше другим способом.
Я, например, делал систему, в которой по SSE json-diff-ы летали...

Comment: Да, задача большая. Но затык был именно в этом. Я не хотел ветвить if'ами. Просто с объектом в котором я хочу изменить данные общение происходит через апи и мне нужно по сути получить только изменения (разницу) которую нужно грузить через все тот же апи.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сделать слияние словарей:

```
dict1 =...
dict2 =...
merged = dict1.copy()
merged.update(dict2)
```

Чтобы сделать сравнение:

```
from pickle import dumps

if dumps(dict1) == dumps(dict2):
    ...
```